# MongoDB and Spring Data performance Issue

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using MongoDB with Spring Data for creating our prototype application. The save operation is very fast but for listing the results the performance is very poor even when their are just 3 to 4 records persisted. Another amazing part is the the performance deteriorates with each consecutive list operation.

Just to give an idea here is the single json which is not the largest in the world.

```
    {
    "enquiryId": "574feac25215eae3e2e1434b",
    "enquiryName": "Mineral Shipment",
    "dateOfEnquiry": null,
    "requiredFrom": 1465324200000,
    "requiredTo": 1483036200000,
    "source": {
      "locationId": null,
      "area": {
        "pincode": null,
        "area": null,
        "city": {
          "cityId": null,
          "cityName": "Panjim",
          "state": {
            "stateId": null,
            "stateName": " Goa 403001",
            "country": {
              "countryId": null,
              "countryName": " India"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "destination": {
      "locationId": null,
      "area": {
        "pincode": null,
        "area": null,
        "city": {
          "cityId": null,
          "cityName": "Ludhiana",
          "state": {
            "stateId": null,
            "stateName": " Punjab 141001",
            "country": {
              "countryId": null,
              "countryName": " India"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "shipment": {
      "shipmentId": null,
      "enquiryId": null,
      "shipmentName": "Mineral Shipment",
      "valueOfGoods": null,
      "categories": [
        {
          "categoryId": null,
          "categoryName": "Hazardous,Flammable",
          "subCategories": null,
          "shipmentId": null
        }
      ],
      "modes": [
        {
          "modeId": null,
          "modeName": "WATER",
          "modeDescription": null,
          "shipmentId": null
        }
      ],
      "items": [
        {
          "itemId": null,
          "itemName": "Coal",
          "shape": null,
          "form": null,
          "dimension": null,
          "weight": null,
          "quantity": null,
          "shipmentId": null
        },
        {
          "itemId": null,
          "itemName": "Nickel",
          "shape": null,
          "form": null,
          "dimension": null,
          "weight": null,
          "quantity": null,
          "shipmentId": null
        }
      ]
    },
    "transportEnquiries": [
      {
        "transportEnquiryId": null,
        "transport": {
          "transportId": null,
          "name": "Flat Bed",
          "mode": {
            "modeId": null,
            "modeName": "WATER",
            "modeDescription": "The two world wars gave a great impetus to the development of air transport in almost all the countries of the world",
            "shipmentId": null
          },
          "type": {
            "typeId": null,
            "name": "LWH",
            "modeId": null,
            "illustrationURL": null
          },
          "desc": "Description of Flat Bed"
        }
      }
    ],
    "storageEnquiries": [],
    "packagingEnquiries": null,
    "insuranceEnquiries": null,
    "documentationEnquiry": null,
    "trackingToolRequired": null,
    "customerSupportRequired": null,
    "insuranceRequired": null,
    "storageRequired": null,
    "documentationRequired": null,
    "published": false,
    "userId": null
  }
```

And here is the Spring Service

```
    public class EnquiryManagementService implements IEnquiryManagementService{

    @Autowired
    private EnquiryRepository enquiryRepository;

    public Enquiry createEnquiry(Enquiry enquiry) {
        Enquiry enquiryObj = (Enquiry)enquiry;
        Enquiry e = enquiryRepository.save(enquiryObj);
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Enquiry> listEnquiry(int start) {
         long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Page<Enquiry> enquiries = enquiryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(start,10));
         long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
         System.out.println("Time Taken = "+(endTime-startTime));
         return enquiries.getContent();
    }



}
```

Here are the results of the times taken in processing the findAll() 4 times consequtively without adding any more records. There are only 4 records in the system and you can see the time taken is 10.7 sec, 25.7 sec, 41.9 sec, and 58.5 sec. Each request takes a lifetime of its own to complete.

- Time Taken = 10768
- Time Taken = 25785
- Time Taken = 41921
- Time Taken = 58530

Given below is the configuration of my system
- Intel Core i3 2330M @2.2 GHz
- 2 GB RAM
- 64 bit Windows 7 
- MongoDB version locally installed on my system : 3.2
- At the time of executing this query CPU utilization 50% and memory 80%

Ideally this operation must happen in less than half a second or at max a second. Any kind of help would be great.

Comment: Please enable the debug log and post the link.

Comment: Do you want me to post the debug log?

Comment: That was the idea.